# Drupal add blank page without styles and js

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have the site based on drupal 7.

I need to create widget for iframe. I created new content type and removed all sidebars, headers, footers from there. I left only content. It works good.

But this page loads all my scripts and css (less) from mytheme.info. And I want just to use scripts and css from my custom module. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`template_process_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7) to do so.

Add the following code to your theme's `template.php` file.

```
function [YOUR_THEME]_process_html(&$vars) {

    // first check for the path of the page you need to unset the js & css for.
    // assuming the path is 'node/12'
    if(arg(0) === 'node' && arg(1) === '12') {
        $vars['scripts'] = array();
        $vars['styles'] = array();
    }
}
```

To check if current page is a specific content type; You can use `$vars['classes']` or `$vars['classes_array']`, which holds the css classes to add to `<body>` tag. In case of a node page, it adds a class name `node-type-NODE_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME` to the classes string.

```
 if(strpos($vars['classes'], 'node-type-[YOUR_TYPE]') === TRUE) {
```

OR

```
 if(in_array('node-type-[YOUR_TYPE]', $vars['classes_array']) === TRUE) {
```

**Update**

You can add any js / css files to the array

```
$vars['scripts'] = array(
    'path/to/js/file1.js',
    'path/to/js/file2.js'
);
$vars['styles'] = array(
    'path/to/css/file1.css',
    'path/to/css/file2.css'
);
```

Comment: $vars['node'] and $vars['scripts'] and else are null in my case!

Comment: Make sure you use `template_process_html` NOT `template_PREprocess_html`

Comment: Updated the answer to check for a content type

Comment: Yes, now this shows scripts and styles, but they are in string, not in array. And I need to add some new styles. Also, as I understand,   scripts, that I added in module - will also removed?

Comment: no, as I said - I need to add scripts and css from module. And it would be good to use less instead of css.
My info has string: stylesheets[all][] = 'less/styles.less'.
I just need to change it with stylesheets[all][] = 'less/widget.less'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65686/discussion-between-sergey-kudryashov-and-muhammad-reda).